# connecting expressions with similar words

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice, titles

I often face this problem in scientific papers. When writing a title I have two possibilities. For example:

- *Enterprise and Process Modelling* or *Enterprise Modelling and Process Modelling*
- *Water Management and Energy Management* or *Water and Energy Management*

Which form is better?

Answer (score 2):

If the noun phrases involved are **short** and **similar in category**, I'd recommend skipping repetition.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your examples, it seems that the following expressions are better:

- Enterprise and Process Modelling
- Water and Energy Management